# Raspbian Lite strech 4.19.40-v7+ on Pi 3+ eth0 not added to bridge on boot

Tags: pi-3, networking, raspbian-stretch, bridge

After following "thousands" of guides I'm about to giving up on it.

Intended setup:
wifi access point with builtin wlan of Pi3. So a bridge of eth0 and wlan0.

- interface names are eth0 and wlan0 (raspi-config config option used)
- dhcpcd.conf uses denyinterfaces eth0 wlan0
- sysctl.conf has ip_forward enabled
- hostapd is configured to work on br0
- /etc/network/interface.d/bridge.conf sets eth0 and wlan0 to manual and br0 to dhcp and adds eth0 and wlan0

The setup works flawlessly until I reboot.
After the reboot eth0 is not part of br0 anymore. (`brctl addif br0 eth0` is neccessary as well as a `dhclient` call.)

What do I do wrong that the configuration is not applied correctly during boot?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an experimental kernel and presumably firmware, probably from running `rpi-update`. There are outstanding issues with the 4.19 kernel.

> "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911
>   Even the [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) documentation now warns "Even on Raspbian you should only use this with a good reason. This gets you the latest bleeding edge kernel/firmware."

`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel`
will put it back to the latest supported kernel/bootcode.

Comment: I actually ran rpi-update because I had the same issue with kernel 4.14.98-v7+ which was there from the fresh install of the image (and regular updates)